# putting foreach loop into a csv file

Tags: powershell

im stuck on how to output my foreach loop into a csv or excel file. this script just get all computers off a local network and then test to see if that computer has a certain KBPatch. The script works just like I said I need help trying to make it output to a csv file. any tips/help is appreciated

Code Below

```
$strCategory = "computer"
$objDomain = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry
$objSearcher = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher
$ObjSearcher.SearchRoot = $objDomain
$objSearcher.filter = ("(objectCategory=$strCategory)")
$colProplist = "name"

foreach($i in $colProplist)
{
    $objSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add($i)
}


#Finds all operating systems and computer names
$colResults = $objSearcher.FindAll()

foreach($objResult in $colResults)
{    
    $objComputer = $objResult.Properties;
    $names = $objComputer.name

# Define Hotfix to check
    $CheckKBS = @(“patch#" , "patch#")

#Query the computers for the HotFix
foreach($name in $names)
{ 
foreach ($CheckKB in $CheckKBS) {
 $HotFixQuery = Get-HotFix -ComputerName $name | Where-Object {$_.HotFixId -eq $CheckKB} | Select-Object -First 1;
 if($HotFixQuery -eq $null)
 {
  Write-Host “Hotfix $CheckKB is not installed on $name”;
 }
 else
 {
  Write-Host “Hotfix $CheckKB was installed on $name by ” $($HotFixQuery.InstalledBy);
 }
 }}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this cleanly I usually use a custom object.

Before your foreach, instantiate an empty array:

```
$records = @()
```

and make an object template:

```
$tmpRecord = [PSCustomObject]@{
  serverName = ''
  missingKB = ''
}
```

Inside the foreach, clone the record obj:

```
$record = $tmpRecord.psobject.copy()
```

put your data into the record:

```
$record.serverName = $name
$record.missingKB = $CheckKb
```

Put the record into the array:

```
$records += $record
```

Then after the foreach, export to csv:

```
$records | export-csv yourcsv.csv
```

The need for an object template was confusing to me when I first learned this pattern. You need this because of the combination of scope and how objects are added to arrays (by reference).

If you try to get away with declaring an object inside the loop then that object will be scoped to the lifetime of the foreach loop. You'll then add a reference to that object to your $records array. After the foreach loop completes you will have an array full of references to objects that do not exist.

Comment: There is no need for the template, you can just build a new custom object in each pass of the ForEach loop. You can strongly type the variable as `[array]$records` in your `$records +=` line, and avoid instantiating it beforehand. Due to how arrays are destroyed and rebuilt each time you use `+=`, it's better to do `[array]$Records = ForEach(){` and have the loop output objects to be collected all at once instead of rebuilding the array over and over.